# Creating faces from only the vertices?

Tags: javascript, merge, three.js

I'm trying to create a minecraft type (only cubes) terrain by merging cubes at the correct positions into one geometry then creating a mesh and drawing it. At the moment I'm sending an array from a Node.JS server which contains the types of block that make up each "chunk". The code then knows the material index to give each block. For example, the data for a 10x10x10 chunk would be:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,
 etc ...             ]
```

This would work fine, but merging each of those blocks into one geometry is time consuming, so doesn't work for my use case.

My idea now is to merge the cubes server-side and then send only the vertices to the client along with the block type array (same as above). So my question is, is it possible to create faces for these vertices so the geometry appears as multiple cubes with different materials?

I feel this would be better as not only would the client-side be less stressed, but the server would only have to merge each chunk once, where as at the moment, each client is required to merge it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks. :)

**EDIT:**
Just had a thought after [reading this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/342). If at initialize I create a geometry that's a whole chunk with blocks, so 10x10x10, then when sent the data array (as above) I could hide the faces of blocks that aren't meant to be there. By hiding, I mean give the face an invisible material. I believe this would be faster, and wouldn't even require me to send the vertices.

In that case, can anyone explain how I would determine which faces to hide? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could create "native" Three.js JSON model directly on the server and just load it up with JSONLoader. Should be fast. It's a bit briefly documented, but here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3.1 , and you can study the sample files on the examples folder. It's quite easy to understand.

In the JSON, you can have multiple materials, and define the material index per face.

Comment: Thanks yaku. Was going to send the whole JSON model, but found that the size was too large. A 10x10x10 chunk would be ~1.3MB where as if I only send the vertices it's ~100KB. That's why I wanted to know if it's possible to add faces to the model using only the vertices (along with the block data in the array). Any ideas? :)